# Azure - I keep losing RDP connectivity to my VMs every now and then

Tags: azure, rdp

I've been evaluating Azure for a couple months. I'm using it via my MSDN subscription. The intention is to determine if my development team should migrate from VMWare to Azure machines.

I managed to setup multiple VMs and work on them successfully. I tend to shut down all VMs as often as I can in order to not use up my monthly resource allowance.

Very often I lose RDP connectivity to all my VMs. Sometimes it helps to resize the VM but not always. I've tried all steps included on the link below, for instance.

What I am missing?

https://azure.microsoft.com/pl-pl/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-troubleshoot-remote-desktop-connections/

Comment: Just because its an obvious question, are you sure it is a problem with the VMs / RDP? I presume by 'lose RDP connectivty' you mean that the connections timeout in mstsc? Have you tried connecting from a different network when its down etc?

Comment: WiFi? We haven't experienced any issues like that, and often times leave sessions open all day long, but also have a pretty good internet connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx guys (and sorry). It was indeed due to network issues (DNS fails on my home internet provider from time to time).